# Valores aleatorios sin repetir

Tags: java, android-studio

estoy desarrollando un juego en android studio y quiero imprimir valores aleatorios alojados en un array sin repetir, con el siguiente código que muestro abajo, los valores que se imprimen si son aleatorios pero se repiten y en mas de una ocasión. El objetivo es que si ya se impriemieron una vez no se vuelvan a repetir una vez que se han impreso todos los valores del array el juego finaliza, es decir solo se debe imprimir una vez cada valor.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

```
   Integer [] images =  {
            R.drawable.ch_cabeza,
            R.drawable.ch_cuerpo_1,
            R.drawable.ch_piernas,
            R.drawable.manos_115,
            R.drawable.ch_pies,
            R.drawable.ch_brazos,
    };

    Integer [] sonidos =  {
            R.raw.cabeza,
            R.raw.cuerpo,
            R.raw.piernas,
            R.raw.brazos,
            R.raw.manos,
            R.raw.perro,
    };


    Integer [] images_numbers = {0,1,2,3,4,5};

    Integer [] sonidos_numbers = {0,1,2,3,4,5};


    private static int getRandom(Integer[] array)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int start = 0;
        int end = 6;
        int playRandom = r.nextInt(end-start) + start;
        return array[playRandom];
    }
```

finalmente el metodo getRandom lo utilizo de la siguiente manera

```
 int valorRandom = getRandom(sonidos_numbers);

                if (valorRandom == 0 )
                {
                    soundPool.play(cabeza,1,1,0,0,1);
                    imagen_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view)
                        {
                            imagen_principal_1.setImageResource(images[images_numbers[0]]);
                            imagen_1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            soundPool.play(correcto,1,1,0,0,1);
                            turns++;

                            checkEnd();
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes tener el registro de los valores que ya ocurrieron o en su defecto los valores disponibles!
Entonces chequeas el random antes de devolverlo, y de ser necesario, volver a generarlo.

En todos los casos debes tener el registro guardado de alguna forma.
El ejemplo siguiente es suponiendo que uses directamente `images` y `sonidos`, entonces estos valores se irán eliminando a medida que los obtengas.

```
private static int getRandom(int[] array)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    // Regresa una posición aleatoria en el array
    int playIndex = r.nextInt(array.length);
    // Guarda el valor
    int playNumber = array[playIndex];
    // elimina la posición del array
    array = removeElement(array,playIndex);
    return playNumber;
}
// Remover una posición de un array
public static int[] removeElement(int[] array, int index) { 
    // Si el array está vacío
    // o el index no está en rango
    // regresa el array original 
    if (arr == null
    || index < 0 || index >= arr.length)
    { 
            return arr; 
    } 

    // Crea otro array con una posición menos
    int[] anotherArray = new int[arr.length - 1]; 

    // Copia elementos del original hasta el index
    // hacia el nuevo array
    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, anotherArray, 0, index); 

    // Copia elementos del original desde el index +1
    // hacia el nuevo array
    System.arraycopy(arr, index + 1, anotherArray, index,  arr.length - index - 1); 

    // retorna el resultado
    return anotherArray; 
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, deberia sustituir el codigo que me envisate en el metodo getRandom que ulizo para que cada vez que me retorne un dato este no se repita

Comment: Por supuesto, las otras dos funciones son simples utilidades. Básicamente cada vez que llames el `getRandom` éste sacará un valor del array te lo devolverá como resultado.

Comment: Se me generan algunos errores al momento de eliminar el valor del array :(

Comment: Allí corregí unos detalles de syntax y te lo simplifiqué aún más.
No estoy muy seguro de la eliminación de una posición en el array puesto que se envía por parámetros, no recuerdo bien si java usa parámetros por referencia implícitamente.

Comment: Bueno he intentado ejecutar el codigo que muy gentilmente me ayudaste y existe un inconveniente al momento de eliminar la posición del array, alguna guia adicional que me puedas ayudar

Comment: Tu error se debe al tipo de datos `Integer` vs `int` y a lo que expliqué anteriormente, no tengo recuerdo si en éste caso, Java pasa el valor por referencia, casi seguro que sí.
 
Como ya mencioné, se trata de eliminar una posición en el `array`, eso ya vendría siendo otra pregunta distinta al tema.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda